# Title of novel about a hitman trying to kill a guy who is a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

I found a book on the library shelves sometime in the 1990s. I assume it was written in that general timeframe, as well, since its style was modern.

The story was about a hitman who is hired to kill another man. This proves to be a difficult task because the target turns out to be a werewolf. The book was fairly short and very action-orientated. Basically, the werewolf guy could take everything the hitman threw at him, up to, and including, a rocket launcher. The rocket launcher blew the werewolf apart, but then he just regenerated.

It was fairly fun book. It didn't take itself too seriously and did not aim any higher than being entertainment.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) guide to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152346/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hm. Perhaps if it was a silver rocket...